# How would I modify my predicate to jumble my output result?

Tags: prolog

So I'm experimenting with some stuff. I have the following simple predicate:

```
insert([],Y,[Y]).
insert([H|T],Y,[H,Y|T]).
```

So this'll insert my element `Y` into my list. However this always puts it in the same place, which is in the middle. But say I wanted it to be more like the following:

```
?- insert([1,2,3], 4, Zs).
```

> should succeed four times and give the following answers:

```
Zs = [4, 1, 2, 3]
Zs = [1, 4, 2, 3]
Zs = [1, 2, 4, 3]
Zs = [1, 2, 3, 4].
```

How would I modify my predicate accordingly?

Comment: It's good to think in terms of what the rules might be, and think in terms of a simple case and a non-overlapping recursive case. Then translate to Prolog...(1) inserting `Y` into list `L` is the list with `Y` as head, and `L` as the tail (rest), and (2) inserting `Y` into the list `[H|T]` is `[H|R]` where `R` is the list `T` with `Y` inserted into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find possible position of an element in a list, then you have to find all possible concatenation of this list containing the element to insert. This can be described using `append/3` predicate:

```
insert(X,Y,Z):- append(A, B, X), append(A, [Y|B], Z).
```

This predicate states that exists a concatenation of two sublist that returns list X, and this two sublist concatenated with the value Y in the head of the second sublist, returns list Z.

```
?- insert([1,2,3], 4, Z).
Z = [4, 1, 2, 3]
Z = [1, 4, 2, 3]
Z = [1, 2, 4, 3]
Z = [1, 2, 3, 4]
false
```

Answer (score 2):

another useful builtin, extended in SWI-Prolog to handle insertion as well as selection:

```
?- nth1(_,X,a,[1,2,3]).
X = [a, 1, 2, 3] ;
X = [1, a, 2, 3] ;
X = [1, 2, a, 3] ;
X = [1, 2, 3, a] ;
false.
```

just ignore first argument (the index itself)